# Stop canvas animation on mouse out

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, mouseover

I am trying to make an interactive banner of rounded rectangles. Those rectangles are animated on mouse over and I want the animation to stop on mouse out. The problem is the animation doesn't stop on mouse out...

You can check (and criticize) my code right here: http://jsbin.com/osevaz/edit#source

Thank you all in advance,

Mehdi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not return timerId in `animate` function

=> `anim` is `undefined`

=> `cancelRequestAnimFrame` doesn't stop animation

Moreover, Firefox (5-8) has `mozRequestAnimationFrame`, but no `mozCancelRequestAnimationFrame`

[Read more](http://blog.joelambert.co.uk/2011/06/01/a-better-settimeoutsetinterval/) about that and cross-browser animation.

Comment: `setTimeout`/`setInterval` returns some number = timerId, which may be later used to stop timer with `clearTimeout`/`clearInterval`. One need to know that return value to stop timer.
`AnimationFrame`-functions work the same way.